# Can't access phpmyadmin, because of a faulty DNS entry

Tags: domain-name-system, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've crashed my domain's DNS trying to enter a DKIM entry to my control panel, now I can't access my domain, my control panel or PHPMyAdmin because they all reside on my domain.

Is there a way I can edit a DB entry from FTP, or I can take out the DKIM entry? because it seems like that is the only way I can access my server files.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may set your desired "A" record in your localhost.
so if your client is Windows,then edit the following file and input the IP address of your web server as below:

for Windows OS:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
>
> 1.2.3.4    Your-URL.com

if Linux, then much easier.

> edit /etc/hosts
>
> 1.2.3.4  Your-URL.com

Then at your browser type.

http://Your-URL.com/phpMyAdmin/

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked!